# int : redefinition (C++)

Tags: c++, addition, calculator, redefinition

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int x, y;
int main()

{

    cout << "Please give me a number:";
    int x = (cin, x);

    cout << "Please give me another number:";
    int y = (cin, y);

    cout << "The sum of " << x;
    cout << "and " << y;
    cout << "is " << x+y;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why(as simple as it is) this doesn't add?
I'm not really sure how to return user input for numbers and the like. Just started learning this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe instead of this:

```
int x = (cin, x);
```

you wanted this:

```
cin >> x;
```

`cin` (**c**onsole **in**put) works pretty much the same way as `cout` (**c**onsole **out**put), which you used properly.

You may want to read about them more:

- [std::cout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/)
- [std::cin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/)

Also, you do not need to redefine `x` and `y` in `main()`, as they are  global variables.

Comment: I'd say you do not need to define `x` and `y` as globals; they're only used in `main()`.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Bad coding practices involving intensive usage of global variables is totally different aspect. Good point, though.

Answer (score 1):

Correct code is :

```
#include <iostream> // for cin,cout we use iostream
#include <stdio.h> // you don't need this header file in this program
#include <string> // also you don't need this header

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   int x,y;
   cout<<"Please give me a number : ";
   cin>>x;
   cout<<"Please give me another number : ";
   cin>>y;
   cout<<"The sum of "<<x<<" and "<< y<<" is "<<x+y;
   return 0;
 }
```

Read [Basic_Syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_basic_syntax.htm)